# Add sequential ids to a column using calculate field

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

So I have a bunch of `ObjectID`s that have `null` `id` values. These null values start from ObjectID `20866` to `21899`. ObjectID `20865` has `id` value `30542` so the next id value for ObjectID `20866` would be `30543` and then so on till ObjectID `21899`.

How can I do this using Python in Calculate Field using a For loop and may be a `++` counter?

I am using `ArcGIS Pro 3.1.1`.

Comment: Just select the null rows, then use field calculator and make the expression: `!objectid! + 9677`.

Comment: Nice thanks for the super quick response, so what's `9677` doing?

Comment: It's the difference between 30542 and 20865.

Comment: Wait don't you think instead of `!objectid!` it should be `!id!` since the first calculated `id` value will be `1 + 30542` where `30542` is the last `id` value before the null `id` values start?

Comment: No.  You should use field calculator on the ID field.  The expression will be ID = `!objectid! + 9677`.

Comment: Nice that worked like a charm, please add it as an answer and I will accept it, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the rows where ID is null, then you can use the field calculator on the ID field with the expression `!objectid! + 9677` since `9677` is the difference in value of your OBJECTID and ID fields.